# How to avoid generation of extra assembly instruction by gcc compiler for an inline assembly function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

I have two questions about generation of assembly code by gcc as a result of using inline assembly function in C file. Let me first explains my situation/code and then I will ask questions.

Situation:

I have defined following macro `NBL2SPM` which calls the `mySimMagic2()` function.

```
#define NBL2SPM(compactCode,MemAdr)          mySimMagic2(SIM_CMD_USER,compactCode,MemAdr)
```

`mySimMagic2()` is defined as below.

```
#define mySimMagic2(cmd, MemAdr, CompactCode) ({        \
void *_arg0 = (MemAdr);\
unsigned long _arg1 = (CompactCode), _res; \
__asm__ __volatile__ (                    \        
    "\tmovq (%%rdx), %%rbx" "\n"\
    "\txchg %%bx, %%bx\n"                     \
    : "=a" (_res)           /* output    */   \
    : "d"(_arg0),                             \
      "c"(_arg1)            /* input     */   \
    : "%rbx" ); /* clobbered */ \
    _res;                                     \
 })
```

I use the macro in C-source file in following way

```
    NBL2SPM(&(DU1.Vin[50000]),0x00000105);
```

And it results into following assembly code.

```
    movq    %rax, -400104(%rbp)
    leaq    -400032(%rbp), %rax
    addq    $200000, %rax
    movq    %rax, -400096(%rbp)
    movq    $261, -400088(%rbp)
    movq    -400096(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -400088(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rdx        
    movq    (%rdx), %rbx
    xchg    %bx, %bx
```

Question 1: Why compiler (gcc) generates assembly instructions (i.e. `movq  %rax, -400096(%rbp)` and `movq  $261, -400088(%rbp)`) to first move the register RAX and immediate value `$261`  to memory and then loads them back from memory into registers (i.e. `movq  -400096(%rbp), %rax` and `movq  400088(%rbp), %rcx`)? What is the purpose/advantage of this storing of data to memory and then loading back the same data to registers?

Question 2: Suppose that I want to avoid this "unwanted" saving of register/immediate value to memory and then loading it back to register. Is there a way to force the compiler (gcc) to not generate these "unwanted" memory store/load instructions.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with optimizations on.Like `-O3`?

Comment: I'm assuming `xchg %%bx, %%bx` is intended to produce some form of debug point?

Comment: I ask about that xchg because it looks rather peculiar (xchg bx,bx doesn't have any useful side effects although some environments use it to trigger a debug break). Your code doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. For instance the assembly template says that _RAX_ is an output yet the assembly template doesn't touch that register at all

Comment: _RCX_ is an input and not used at all either

Comment: Someone else is bound to ask, so I may as well do it now. What are you intending this code to do for you? What problem are you trying to solve with this macro/assembly template? For instance are you trying to get _RAX_ returned to you in _res and all those unnecessary load/stores happens to clobber that register? If so your approach is flawed and effectively is undefined behaviour.

Comment: As suggested by Michael Petch, compiling with -O3 optimizations removes those "unwanted instructions" from generated assembly. Thanks all for quick response. I will get back to this thread if face some other problem related to same topic/subject.

Comment: -O3 doesn't guarantee that all such loads/stores will be eliminated. you are just lucky it outputs code you want, but it is a very bad idea to rely on such behaviour. I really hope this isn't for production code. If I saw it in a code review I'd be using way too many WTFs to describe what I think about this code.

Comment: let me respond to your comments above:
1) XCHG: The code is executed ona simulator. On encountering the  Xchg bx, bx instruction, simulator call a "handler function". SO the sole purpose of putting "Xchg bx, bx" instruction here is to invoke that handler function.
2) RBX: You are right about RAX. I can remove it from the assembly template.
3) RCX: I just want the compiler to place _arg1 (i.e. Compactcode) in RCX. Then simulators uses the content of RCX in "handler function". I do not need to touch RCX in assembly template.

Comment: 4) I do not need any retrn value from this assembly template. I only want to make sure that i) compatcode (i.e. immediate number $261 is in RCX), ii) MemAddr is in RDX, iii) Data is loaded from Mem[RDX] into RBX and iv) Xchg bx, bx is executed. I want to avoid unnecessary load/stores.

If -O3 is not the gauranteed way to avoid load/store, what is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Why are extra load stores an issue? Do they cause your code to fail? It can't guarantee no load stores. if the optimizer runs out of available registers it may have to do a load/store to free something up. In that case it isn't an unnecessary load/store but it is a load/store nonetheless.

Comment: Extra load stores does not fit with the purpose of functionality I am trying to implement within "handler function".

I don not understand whats the purpose of storing a value in register RAX first, then moving content of RAX into a memory location, then loading from same memory loaction into RAX as shown in following code. I dont think it is done to solve the problem of limited registers. The data is already in RAX before saving it to memory.

        addq    $200000, %rax
        movq    %rax, -400096(%rbp)
        movq    $261, -400088(%rbp)
        movq    -400096(%rbp), %rax

Comment: The code generator is free to produce any code it needs to get the job done. When you rely on code to be generated a specific way then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: `"d"(_arg0)` doesn't tell the compiler that you're going to dereference that pointer, so it doesn't treat `*_arg0` as an input, only `_arg0` itself.  Why not just ask for `*_arg0` in `%rbx` in the first place, and only put the `xchg %%bx, %%bx` in your asm statement?  Or depending what your handler does, you may need a `"memory"` clobber anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug in [GCC tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) (they might ask you to repro with latest trunk or at least latest release).